# Sql to NHibernate QueryOver

Tags: sql, nhibernate, queryover

How can I Convert this SQL to NHibernate QueryOver ?

```
select k1.Id,k.sm
from tblKarbarg_1 k1
inner join (
            select kd.Karbarg_1_id,SUM(kd.MablaghSanad) as sm 
            from tblKarbarg_1_Detail kd 
            group by kd.Karbarg_1_id
            ) K 
on k.Karbarg_1_id=k1.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your mapping. But here is a very nice list of examples that demonstate the feautures of QueryOver and other methods of querying in NHibernate.

http://www.martinwilley.com/net/code/nhibernate/query.html